# How to prevent requestAnimationFrame() flickering in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, requestanimationframe

I am trying to find a fix for the `requestAnimationFrame()` **method in IE 11**. I have been browsing the web to find a solution. So far, I have tried to include **polyfills**, but the bug doesn't go away.

Does anybody has solution for IE11 bug?

This is an [example](https://jsbin.com/yukodicunu/1/edit) using jQuery 3.4 which uses `requestAnimationFrame()` method for the `fadeToggle()` method. You will be able to check the flickering in **IE11**.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that causes this issue?

Comment: @Aplet123 thanks for the reply! I have edited my question. Let me know if you need more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve the issue by using one of the suitable way mentioned below.

1. ADD A BACKGROUND COLOR
   Set a background color with CSS on the element that is fading in or out. This is the most basic way to solve the problem.
2. REMOVE THE CLEARTYPE FILTER
   After fading in an element you can add this simple callback function to fix the bug.

```js
$('#fadingElement').fadeIn(2000, function(){
       this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
});
```

3. USE A CUSTOM FADEIN/OUT METHOD
   This method serve’s as a replacement for the built-in fadeIn() & fadeOut() methods for jQuery.

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.customFadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
        $(this).fadeIn(speed, function() {
            if(jQuery.browser.msie)
                $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
            if(callback != undefined)
                callback();
        });
    };
    $.fn.customFadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
        $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
            if(jQuery.browser.msie)
                $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
            if(callback != undefined)
                callback();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

References:

(1) [jQuery fadeIn & fadeOut Problems in Internet Explorer](https://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/)

(2) [How to Fix jQuery's Fade In/Out Functions for Internet Explorer](https://www.epochdev.com/blog/tutorials/javascript_development/fixing_jquery_fade_in_and_out_functions_for_internet_explorer)

**Note: I had added the code in snippet because this site was not formatting the code properly using code block.**

Comment: Can you show us, how did you try to use it and what did you tested on your side? It can help to understand the issue in better way.